# i18n render certain view based on language selected

Tags: node.js, express, internationalization

I'm not sure whether i18n is suited for this. As it seems this module is only focused on changing language properties (inside a view render) but not the views itself. I hope I explain myself well enough :)

So the idea is when a person changes language the render chooses the view (with the same filename) from the language directory.

You can have for example such directory hierarchy:

```
-views
--EN
---index.jade
---contact.jade
--NL
---index.jade
---contact.jade
--form-contact.jade
```

To be clear, the `'form-contact.jade'` file would contain the form (which is included in the `'contact.jade'` file. So `'form-contact.jade'` would indeed make use of the **i18n alias** objects (which would reside in the en.json or nl.json file).

So as for now I only have the following:

**app.js**

```
i18n.configure({
  locales: ['en', 'nl'],
  directory: __dirname + '/locales',
  defaultLocale: 'en',
  extension: '.json',
  register: global
});

app.use(i18n.init);

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(i18n);
  if (req.query.lang != undefined && i18n.locales.indexOf(req.query.lang) >= 0) {
    i18n.setLocale(req.query.lang);
  }else{
    i18n.setLocale(i18n.defaultLocale);
  }
  next();
});
```

Now, how do I get the res.render to pick the right view?

```
router.get('/contact', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('/contact', { title: '...', menu: '...' });
});
```

***EDIT:***

If you guys have suggestions on translating large static pages (full of html/css) please do give your opinion :)

Comment: Why would you need a different view per language?

Comment: As most pages are static. I first thought of putting it into the json language files but it would be to messy and long.

Comment: First step set the client device language to the desired language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your way is wrong.
if you have view for every language, then what's the point to use i18n?

You can just get

```
?lang=
```

value and send `res.render ( '/' + req.query.lang + '/contact.html').`

*Try way is*

```
-locales
--en.json
--nl.json
-view
--cabinet.html
--main.html
```

**app.js**

```
i18n.configure({
    locales: ['en', 'nl'],
    directory: __dirname + '/locales',
    defaultLocale: 'nl',
    updateFiles: false,
    objectNotation: true
});

app.use(i18n.init);

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(i18n);
  if (req.query.lang != undefined && i18n.locales.indexOf(req.query.lang) >= 0) {
    i18n.setLocale(req.query.lang);
  }else{
    i18n.setLocale(i18n.defaultLocale);
  }
  next();
});
```

**en.json** example

```
{
    "cabinet": {
        "menu": {
                "title": "Menu",
        },
        "dashboard": {
            "title": "Dashboard"
        },
        "statistic": {
            "datePeriod": "Date period",
            "choose": "Choose",
        }
    },
    "main": {
         "title": "Main",
         "body": {
                  "hi": "Hi everyone!"
         }
    }
```

same for nl.json

**main.html**

```
       I use Swig template
<html>
<head>
      <title>{{ translate.title }}</title>
</head>
<body>
      {{ translate.body.hi }}!! 
</body>
</html>
```

**router.js**

```
router.get('/main', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('/main', { title: '...', menu: '...', translate: res.__('main') });
});

router.get('/cabinet', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('/cabinet', { title: '...', menu: '...', translate: res.__('cabinet') });
});
```

Comment: I understand that but the problem I have is: there are 8 static pages with about 150 to 200 lines of code (5% of this are tags, 95% translated text). If I put the text of all these 8 pages into the lang.json file, it would be way to big and chaotic.

Comment: Why chaotic? Just create comfortable object and use dot notation or remove i18n and render **res.render ( '/' + req.query.lang + '/contact.html').**

Comment: I'd like to add that using a language query parameter is **NOT** in anyway a recommended way of doing this when considering SEO. Take a look here for an excellent answer about this: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/403/how-should-i-structure-my-urls-for-both-seo-and-localization/44289#44289

Comment: Just use separate pages or a front-end framework like angular where you could go: ```<div if-language="en">my english text</div><div if-language="fr">mon texte français</div>```

Answer (score 0):

Just use separate pages like @cheks mentioned or, better, a front-end framework like `Angular` where you could go:

`<div if-language="en">my english text</div>
<div if-language="fr">mon texte français</div>`